# Mismatch between row sum and column sum when hide any value from row or column in PRD cross tab report

Tags: pentaho

I have to hide some member either from row or column (like `[Markets].[APAC]`). When I hide this member then in "Grand Total" still showing the count of hidden column.

Here is sample query ... similar to my requirement....

```
select NON EMPTY Except({Hierarchize(Union({[Markets].[All Markets]}, [Markets].[All Markets].Children))}, {[Markets].[APAC]}) ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY Hierarchize(Union({[Product].[All Products]}, [Product].[All Products].Children)) ON ROWS
from [SteelWheelsSales]
where {[Measures].[Sales]}
```

Please provide solution on this ..

Thanks in advance.

Sagar

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of context here, but assuming you are an EE customer doing this in Analyzer, there are a couple of relevant options:

1. Under "Report Options", or by right-clicking on the Grand Total label, there is a check box to toggle display of totals that include filtered out values.  Depending on your version, which you did not specify, this may be defaulted to include the filtered out values.  Unchecking it would correct your problem.
2. Also check out the "Subtotals" option in your measure's right-click menu to ensure your aggregation type is correct for your purpose.